# Make iron-router go to same page with different parameters

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

Iron-router is preventing my template from rendering a new page because it seems to believe it is already there.

The routes that I am dealing with are these:

```
Router.route('/', {
  name: 'landingpage',
  template: 'landingpage',
  onBeforeAction: function() {
    this.next();
  }
});

Router.route('/chapter/:pathSlug/:chapterSlug', {
  name: 'chaptershow',
  template: 'chaptershow',
  //waitOn: function() {
    //return [Meteor.subscribe('users'),
            //Meteor.subscribe('ChapterCollection')];
  //},
  onBeforeAction: function() {
    Session.set('currentRoute', 'chapter');
    this.next();
  }
});
```

Let's say I have two chapters I want to display:

```
/chapter/voyage/somestories
/chapter/voyage/someotherstories
```

From the console I can easily go from the landingpage to either of the voyage pages or vice versa with

```
Router.go('landingpage');
Router.go('/chapter/voyage/somestories');
```

However, if I am on `/chapter/voyage/somestories` and try to go to `/chapter/voyage/someotherstories` using either

```
Router.go('/chapter/voyage/someotherstories');
Router.go('chaptershow', {pathSlug: 'voyage', chapterSlug: 'someotherstories'});
```

the URL in the location bar changes to `/chapter/voyage/someotherstories` but the new context doesn't load.

How do I get my new chapter to render?

Comment: And what about when your subscriptions are not commented out?

Comment: It's not really a solution, but you could try abusing a **Session variable** holding the parts or a document ID (`_id`) which is used to determine the view content. Session variables are reactive as well and I think you can control them easier (they tend not to change automatically and explicit set and get are available).

Comment: Try including a `data:` definition in your route. This should load whatever document corresponds to the slug. https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#rendering-templates-with-data